# How much is the average subscriptions amount (sum amount subscriptions / count subscriptions) breakdown by year/month (format YYYY-MM)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently trying to complete a SQL exercise on BigQuery. I don't really understand the question being asked. Could anyone help with interpreting this?

[image]

Comment: Hint: The avg() function will aggregate your groups.

Answer (score 0):

If your table not contains month column, you can create it for example in 2022, every month's individual subscription count and
sum & avg amounts can be taken with this query:

```
select
avg(case when Status = 'Active' then amount end) as avg_ 
count(case when Status = 'Active' then id end) as cnt_
sum(case when Status = 'Active' then amount end) as sum_,
case when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-31' then '2022-01-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-28' then '2022-02-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-31' then '2022-03-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-04-01' and '2022-04-30' then '2022-04-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-05-01' and '2022-05-31' then '2022-05-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-06-01' and '2022-06-30' then '2022-06-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-07-01' and '2022-07-31' then '2022-07-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-31' then '2022-08-01'
     when cast(startdate as date) between '2022-09-01' and '2022-09-30' then '2022-09-01' end as month 
    from reference_table 
    group by 4
```